# Access Webmin from other computers

Tags: arch-linux

I have just installed Webmin on an Arch Linux distro, but I can access it only on the box itself: https://localhost:10000. When I try it from my work computer it doesn't work. I added "allow=127.0.0.1 my.i.p.here" in /etc/webmin/miniserv.conf but it is of no use. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Check-list :

1. webmin works locally,
2. the webmin server listens from remote addresses,
3. the remote host can listen port 10000 on the webmin server's host,

1 and 2 seem OK, you checked 3?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you restart webmin after any changes
2. If you have enabled firwall make sure you add a rule to access the webmin port.

Answer (score 0):

IF it's like my linux box, sitting behind a huge firewall in the office I actually disabled the firewall on the linux box itself as this server is never going to have public acces. Possible idea if you are in a similar situation.

Alternatively, I beleive you can use this command to allow port 10000 access:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT
```

That is how I got webmin working before I decided to disable the firewall.